# Moodle Plugin "Respondus" will not Authenticate since move to WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, moodle, wso2-identity-server

We moved our SSO services from F5 BigIp to WSO2 Identity Server. The moodle saml plugin we are using is OneLogin (https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_onelogin_saml).
Authentication works fine in most ways. Our issue is that we use an Moodle plugin named Respondus (Respondus 4.0, https://www.respondus.com/download/moodleserver.shtml). There is a client side application that an end user would post tests and quizzes directly into moodle. 
This where the process fails, the client side application has fields for the user details to log into Moodle. [Picture of error in app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMETO.jpg)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue on the moodle plugin side with an incorrect value.

Answer (score 0):

You have written, "Authentication works fine in most ways.".

Can you be more specific? What are the most ways you have checked?

What's your Moodle version?

Comment: Logging into moodle via the WSO2IS works every time, the other plugins work without issues. Sorry that may have been a poor choice of words. I was trying to communicate that this is the only issue we have had so far since moving to WSO2IS for authentication. We are on Moodle Version 3.4.2. So far in the WSO2 logs I cannot find any log of the attempt. Thank you for looking into this issue.

Comment: Do u see any logs in http access logs of the Identity Server

Comment: No there are no logs, however I do not have debug turned on.